# How can I ask Eclipse to always prefer the newest version of a library that is included by other libraries?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, version, hamcrest

My project uses junit-4.8.2.jar and mockito-all-1.8.5.jar; both includes Hamcrest 1.1. This is working just fine until I added hamcrest-all-1.2.jar; now I get various NoSuchMethodError, because apparently my code compiles to Hamcrest 1.2, but is being run with Hamcrest 1.1.

It looks like there are various ways to solve this problem (e.g. use junit-dep-4.8.2 instead, etc), but is there a way to tell Eclipse to prefer Hamcrest 1.2. at run-time as well as compile-time?

Comment: That's one of the reasons why people use Maven, you know :-)

Comment: Placing `hamcrest-all-1.2.jar` before the others in the list of project testing libraries doesn't do this?

Answer (score 2):

It was already mentioned in the comments, but i think it's also a valid answer: Use Maven to handle the dependency management. If you don't want to use Maven (because you already use Ant or anything like that), use Ivy, Gradle, Buildr or any other build tool with dependency management.